# JavaFX GridPane Drag and Drop with a dynamic amount of Labels

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, drag-and-drop

At the moment I am struggling with a JavaFX problem. I will try to explain it as detailed as possible. If you need any further information, just let me know!

What do I want to achieve:

- In the picture below you can see what I am trying to achive
- I am creating a variable number of Labels (the amount will differ from time to time)
- The references to this labels are stored in an ArrayList. The Labels then are placed on the GridPane
- Now I want to be able to drag and drop that Labels in the GridPane
- I would like to achieve a solution like in the picture below
- When you drag a Label it should be visually shown, where I am dragging it to
- When passing another Label the visual effect should show, what happens when I drop it here (nr. 3 in the picture). After I drop the Label there, the Labels on the right are switching their position one field to the right. The opened space where I took the source have to be filled with the Labels on the right.

Here is the picture of what I am dreaming right now

[image]

At the moment I am able to create the Labels and place them on the GridPane. But when I try to use an inner class for the .onDragListener I am getting the message, that the Label has to be final. But I can't make it final, because it was created during the runtime and the references are stored in an ArrayList.

Okay here is some Code. I hope it helps.

```
public class Center {

    public static GridPane createCenterContent(List<Tour> tourList){

        GridPane gridPaneCenter = new GridPane();
        final List<List<Label>> customerLabelList = new ArrayList<List<Label>>();
        Label customerLabel = new Label();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < tourList.size() ; i++){
            customerLabelList.add(i, new ArrayList<Label>());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < tourList.get(i).getTour().size() ; j++){
                customerLabelList.get(i).add(new Label(tourList.get(i).getTour().get(j).getVorname() + " " + tourList.get(i).getTour().get(j).getNachname() + " \n" +
                        tourList.get(i).getTour().get(j).getStrasse() + " \n" + tourList.get(i).getTour().get(j).getAdresse()));

                customerLabelList.get(i).get(j).getStyleClass().add("kdLabelGridLayout");
                customerLabelList.get(i).get(j).setMinWidth(200);
                customerLabelList.get(i).get(j).setMinHeight(100);
                customerLabel = customerLabelList.get(i).get(j);

                customerLabel.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
                        /* allow any transfer mode */
                        Dragboard db = customerLabel.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                        System.out.println("Label wird bewegt!");

                    }
                });

                customerLabelList.get(i).get(j).setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data is dragged over the target */
                        /* accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node 
                         * and if it has a string data */

                       event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);

                       System.out.println("Label berührt anderes Label");

                    }
                });             
                gridPaneCenter.add(customerLabelList.get(i).get(j), i, j, 1, 1);
            }
        }
        gridPaneCenter.setHgap(10);
        gridPaneCenter.setVgap(10);

        return gridPaneCenter;
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on the Dragboard db = customerLabel.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY); line. Eclipse tells me that the variable has to be final.
I have a List which contains Lists of Labels. I am placing that Labels in the GridPane and trying to give them all the drag and drop listeners. The amount of labels in the List> differs from time to time.

What can I do to solve the problem? I am very thankful for any hint or link you guys can provide me with.

Comment: The title talk about a BorderPane, is there any BorderPane in your program?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the BorderPane and the GridPane. Title is changed. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: Post the relevant code for the actual problem. From what you describe, the issue is simply that you are having trouble scoping the variables so that they can be used in an anonymous inner class; however it's not at all clear why that would be the case.

Comment: Okay guys, I have posted the code of the relevant class. I hope this helps to understand my problem.

Comment: Can you declare the label inside the second loop? That should solve the scope problem.

Comment: Why do you declare `customerLabel` outside of the loop? Furthermore why do you initialize it with a new `Label` instance that you never use? BTW: Just move the declaration to the line where you read it from the list and add the `final` modifier. Also: This kinf od drag&drop will not work well with the kind of behaviour you're trying to achieve, since it uses the system clipboard and is meant for d&d between applications. Better use the other type of drag events.

Comment: @fabian hey, thanks! What do you mean with the other type of drag events? Could you post me a link or sth where I can try to dive into it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html